# How to remove everything from an Android device?

Tags: adb, mount, formatting

I would like to remove all files from my android device INCLUDING system files. I have tried

> rm -r *

and other commands but when I switch the phone off the files reappear.

Comment: You don't have permission to delete anything from a read-only filesystem like the system itself. The most you can do is delete all user data.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this from the OS or adb, you would have to do it from fastboot or recovery such as CWM or TWRP.

`fastboot erase all` - note this will erase **EVERYTHING**, including your IMEI or MEID and other proprietary settings, the phone will likely be unrecoverable or unusable with most devices. It is blocked in some devices. **Use with caution** and understand the implications prior to doing this!!!

`fastboot erase XXXX` - Where XXXX is the partition you want to delete, like system, boot, userdata, etc.

In TWRP or CWM, you could just format the various partitions.

In most devices, these options would require an unlocked bootloader.

Comment: To emphasize: erasing everything on a phone is likely to hard brick it, unlike, say, erasing a computer's entire hard drive, which you could later set back up.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Although I don't doubt this, why is this the case?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Two possibilities: first, some partitions contain critical information specific to each individual phone, so it can't be restored from a stock factory image, and second, unless there's flashing code burned into ROM, "everything" includes the code that lets you flash new images.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the updates.  What specific information is unique to each individual phone that would prevent it from working?  I'm thinking that if, perhaps, several MAC addresses are stored, the user could use any valid MAC addresses and the phone would technically still work (although there could potentially be conflict issues).  I have a hunch you are thinking of other things though.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket MAC addresses and IMEI or MEID number primarily... Once the IMEI/MEID number is gone, the phone cannot be registered on a mobile network. Many people also forget about the serial number, if that goes away then nothing can be done with security on the device as everything is based on the serial number and you cannot generate an "unlock token" needed by some OEM's to unlock the device. There is also the partition that contains the radio firmware, if they are wiped it may not be possible to restore connectivity to the radios (mobile data/voice, wifi, bluetooth, etc).